# one sample t test by grouping variable with more than 2 groups

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I am having trouble finding any examples of one sample t test comparing the group mean to zero where the grouping is not binary, in R. For example comparing the heights by ethnicity to 5 ft (not comparing against each other). t.test with mu=5 would give an error because the grouping variable is not binary.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a one-sample $t$-test, there is no grouping variable: you just compare all your observations to the mean posited by the null hypothesis.

If you want a $t$-test with a grouping variable, then you're presumably thinking of an independent-samples or dependent-samples $t$-test, but both of these are about comparing two things, and hence R requires any grouping variable to be binary. If you want to compare more than two groups, then perhaps you want ANOVA instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was thinking more about how to do it in R. In SPSS I would split the data by category and then run a one sample t test on each of them. In R it seems that there is no standard method (eg. t.test) to do so.

Comment: Oh, so you meant to ask how to run a one-sample $t$-test within each group? That's just a programming problem, and depends on how your data is organized. Try using `subset` or `aggregate`.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. I figured out a way using the split function.